# MacOS Finder sorts alphabetically differently than Python .sort()

Tags: python, finder, alphabetical-sort

I have three files:

```
x10.txt
x30.txt
x200.txt
```

If I go to my MacOS finder and sort by name I get the following order:

```
x10.txt
x30.txt
x200.txt
```

I am trying to get them in the same order in Python. I am using the following code:

```
mypath = '/path/to/files/'
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
files.sort()
```

But get this order:

```
x10.txt
x200.txt
x30.txt
```

Is there a way in Python to sort these files in the same order as they appear in Finder? I am wondering if there are multiple different conventions for alphabetical order.

Comment: Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304983/clean-up-by-name-isnt-sorting-my-files-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: Do all the filenames follow a format similar to `[SOME-TEXT][NUMBER].[FILE-ENDING]`?

Comment: Finder does a "natural sort", which treats numbers in the filename specially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). Numbers are sorted by numerical value, separately from the rest of the string.

If you're looking for a library, you can use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
>>> import natsort
>>> l = ['x10.txt', 'x30.txt', 'x200.txt']
>>> natsort.natsorted(l)
['x10.txt', 'x30.txt', 'x200.txt']
```

Comment: A better way is to use
```
import os
from natsort import os_sorted
print(os_sorted(l))
```

Comment: `natsort`'s `os_sorted` doesn't reproduce Finder's sort order without `pyicu` installed